# How to fix top margin of background image glitching in Internet Explorer. Fine in others

Tags: html, iframe, formatting

The background image is off vertically.

It looks completely fine in other browsers.

It's an iframe display by the way.

Here is the code that I use within body for the table:

```
<table width="647" height="875" border="0" cellpadding="0" table style="background-image:url(images/main_window.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; position:relative; top:0px; left:0px" align=center>
```

The funny thing is I have exactly the same code for "Shop" section, but it displays just fine in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see it with IE, but I do see it with chrome, which is odd. However I think your host server is down, because I started getting 404 page cannot be found.. (or you took the iframe src down..)

Why don't you try different approach? Something that'd be unified for all browser, because otherwise you'll keep getting misinterpreted source, unless you spend enough time writing conditional css for the different browsers. May be some JS and a few wrapper divs would be much easier to handle, or at least much better looking. Just proposing :)

Cheers!

Comment: Oh, you might get the 404 error if you refresh too much. The server is not down, it's just an oddity. I would like to simplify this, however I'm not an expert. It's really just simple content - a few lines of text, added within a table. Are you saying I should use a div wrap instead of the table?

Comment: Found the problem. It was due to too much text, that went out of borders in IE. Removed 2 questions that were unneeded and it's fixed.